# The charater at the end of an array after you explode url

Tags: php, string, url, explode

if the url is like `$url=artists/denaro/` and i go `explode("/",$url)`. it leaves a character in there is it a space or what as im trying to match and remove it like so

```
$lastelement = end($named_request_data);
if($lastelement == " ")
{
  unset($lastelement);
  reset($named_request_data);
  return $named_request_data;

}
```

Comment: i suppose i could rtrim($url) before but still i want a answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array_filter() instead. It will remove empty items.

```
$string = "artists/denaro/";
$array = array_filter(explode('/', $string));
```

$array will now only contain 'artists' and 'denaro'.

Outputs:

```
array (size=2)
      0 => string 'artists' (length=7)
      1 => string 'denaro' (length=6)
```

Answer (score 0):

It leaves an empty string at the final index of the array.

You should do

```
$url = "artists/denaro/";
$url = trim($url, "/");
$arrayUrl = explode("/", $url);
```

Comment: if it was an empty sttring shouldnt " " or "" match it??

Comment: @Alex " " is not an empty string. That is a string of one white space character. try this: var_dump(' ');

Answer (score 0):

```
        $url='artists/denaro/';
        $exp = explode("/",$url);
        var_dump($exp); //1
        $exp = array_filter($exp);
        var_dump($exp);//2
```

output is:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(7) "artists" [1]=> string(6) "denaro" [2]=> string(0) "" } //1
array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "artists" [1]=> string(6) "denaro" } //2
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php 
"If no callback is supplied, all entries of input equal to FALSE (see converting to boolean) will be removed."

Answer (score 0):

You could use substr to first remove the last character.

PHP Fiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/bfi-yr6

Your original code:

```
$url='artists/denaro/';
$parts = explode("/",$url);
var_dump($parts);
```

outputs:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(7) "artists" [1]=> string(6) "denaro" [2]=> string(0) "" }
```

Using substr:

```
$url2 = substr($url, 0, -1);
$parts2 = explode("/",$url2);
var_dump($parts2);
```

outputs:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "artists" [1]=> string(6) "denaro" }
```